# Where to extract Mako?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to embed Python in Html. Based on your past suggestions, I'm trying to install Mako. My question:
Where should I extract Mako after downloading ? My website project is on drive E. If I extract Mako in drive C (not in the directory that contains the project file), after I transferred my website to the host server, can the python source code function properly in the html ? What about PHP installation? Thanks.

Comment: What web framework are you using? (most of them ship with a templating engine out of the box, and for some of them, like Pyramid, it *is* Mako)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea of web framework? I am writing my html code on notepad.I downloaded django but didn't use it so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mako is a normal Python package. Unless you're using a framework that already integrates it, you install it in the same ways you install *any* Python package—using `pip` or `easy_install`, or `python setup.py installer`, or double-clicking the Windows .msi or .exe, etc.

If you haven't read [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html), you should. You will need to learn how to install modules that you download, rather than just bang at this one without understanding what you're doing, cross your fingers, and repeat as soon as you need another package.

However, there are two easy ways.

---

The [Download Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/download.html) page explicitly suggests that you install it via `pip`. This is always easy, once you've got `pip` working. You don't even have to download the package or know where to find it, just how to type its name. If `pip` is on your %PATH% and set up properly, it's just:

```
C:\> pip install mako
```

If you have `pip`, but it's not on your %PATH%, put it there. If you don't know how to do that, search SuperUser for how to modify the environment for your version of Windows.

If you don't have `pip`, [get it](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip). (If you don't have a C compiler set up, you will probably want to do that at some point as well, but you shouldn't need it for Mako.)

---

Or, you can look at Christoph Gohkle's site to see if he has pre-built Windows binary installer packages for Mako, as he does for many popular packages. And [he does](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mako).

---

Meanwhile, your questions are very confused:

> after I transferred my website to the host server, can the python source code function properly in the html ?

If the host server has some way of running Python scripts, and it has Mako installed into the site-packages of the appropriate Python interpreter, and you're using something that can execute Mako templates, then yes.

Otherwise, no. Mako is not a web development framework or a full web server, much less something that magically transforms a web server on a complete different computer magically into a server. You will need some way of running those Mako templates on the server.

> What about PHP installation?

Um… No thanks?

What's your question here? There *may* be a PHP framework that can drive Mako templates, but I wouldn't expect there to be one, and I wouldn't recommend searching for one. What you want is a *Python* framework. Many Python frameworks can use Mako, but you have to pick one, set it up, and learn how it works.